# Using weight in geometric network to Find Path Upstream

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, trace

I have a problem about using weights in geometric network in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2. In the example below, I have a simple network with a source & some junctions. I'm trying to use the Find Path Upstream function to find path from point A to the source. I've created a weight based on the length of the edge feature, but it seem doesn't work. Can anyone tell me or show me:

- How can I set up a weight to Find Path Upstream from point A to the source through the shortest path (which means A-B-C-D-E-Source in this example)?
- Which weight should I use & how can I set it up if I want to find path from A-F-Source?

[image]

@Hornbydd: Of course I did set the flow direction & a weight by length but it can't return the result I expect. You can see in the image below is what I receive when I use the Find Path Upstream from A.

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2

Comment: I really need help, please someone give me an idea :(

Comment: If you're using Find Path Upstream, maybe you're using the wrong tool. There's a Find Shortest Path tool that takes weights, and if no weights are present does it by the fewest edges. Presumably you'd use your length field of edges as weight.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your comment. It's the Find Path function you mentioned, It works fine but I have to set flag to junction & source. In my case I have many junctions & I need to find path from those junctions to the "source" feature without set flag to "source", so I think I need to use the Find Path Upstream. But the issue is how can I solve that case?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked with geometric network traces really, I was just going off help file searches. I guess I'm not really understanding why you can't set the source, or maybe that you're trying to do two things at once - both find a source and find the shortest path to that source. Perhaps someone with more experience using those trace/path tools can help.

Comment: Don't worry Chris, the Find Path Upstream is the function to find the path from junction to source, but what i'm trying to do is using weight to do it in a loop-network to find the shortest path. But thank you very much anw, I'm still waitting for somebody can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you setup a weight based on the lenght of your network edges (what you have done so far) then you will get (ABCDE) path.
2. If you need to get AF path, then you should setup a based on the number of junctions along the path. To do so, create a weight (Integer), and assign a numeric field of your Junction FeatureClass to that weight. 
   Let say you have a Junction1 FeatureClass. Then add a field (called NetworkWeight) to that class and fill its value with number 1. 
   In this scenario the network path finder looks into the this field once encountered a junction and then consider the junction's weight. The more junction along the way, the more expensive the path.

Comment: Thanks Farid, I did exactly as you said but this can only work with Find Path, but I want to use the Find Path Upstream, any idea please?

Comment: Based on the snapshot you shared, you need to establish flow directions based on the AncillaryRole Field. There are some indeterminate edges on your graph.

Comment: Hi Farid, I did set the flow direction, you can see the Source junction in the  snapshot. The point is from those indeterminate edges, so does the Find Path Upstream can't solve in that case

Comment: When the terms upstream and downstream are used with network trace solvers (like Find Path Upstream), all network directions must be set and determine. The trace will stop at edges that are undetermined or uninitialized.

Comment: Please value the effort of others that are helping you by up-voting and marking the "Correct Answer". See [tour](www.gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks Farid, but in ArcGIS Resources said that weight can be used with Find Path Upstream trace task. So if it must be used with the determined direction network, maybe we don't need weight (because the path is unique in this case)

Comment: This is the reason that Find path works and Find Upstream or Find Downstream won't work with your situation. If you establish flow directions based on digitized direction you will get the for those indetermined edges

Comment: Well, I can't, it must be established based on the Source. Okay so the thing is Find Path Upstream only work with determined edges. Hmm I see it now. Thanks Farid, I think I have to find another solution for this

Comment: I used the geometric network editing tool to disconnect a line in my network so it became undetermined and can confirm the find path upstream would not trace the shortest route, so @FaridCher is right you need to ensure those edges are connected and have their flow direction set.

Comment: I see, @hornydd. At first, I thought the Find Path Upstream is the same with Find Path except in the Find Path Upstream we always have a source/sink as a flag junction. Anyway thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Trace Geometric Network](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015r000000) gp tool and set the Junctions as flags

[image]

Comment: It the same with the trace task, stiil not work. The point is I have a loop at B-C-D-E-F, how to do the Find Path Upstream from A to Source through that loop. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the [flow direction](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Flow_direction_in_a_geometric_network/002r0000002m000000/) of the network? You need to run this [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Set_Flow_Direction/00170000016r000000/). The Trace upstream should then behave. For the record I had to set the weight field (which was length) to be *against* the digitized direction to make the trace follow the shortest route to source. I am unsure how this would influence a trace in a more complex scenario such as a river network?
[image: Upstream Trace and weighting]

Comment: Hi Hornbydd, how could your task complete correctly? Is there any indetermined edges in your network?