# Creating barriers based on distance along geometric network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geometric-network

I have a task at work that requires that I select 1 mile of line (pipe) downstream from a specific point (manhole) in a network.  Each line in the network has a different length, so I need the sum of the length of lines to be around 5280 ft.  I have roughly 300 points within the network, so I'm looking for an automated way to do this.

So far, I've used the geometric network trace tool to trace downstream from each point (flag).  I need to add a barrier along the each downstream route at around 5280 feet.  Does anyone have an idea for how I can accomplish this?

I'm currently using ArcGIS 103.1 Advanced without a Network Analysis license.  I am also using the geometric network toolset to create my network.

[image]

Comment: This Q&A may have some useful suggestions - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155295/using-weight-in-geometric-network-to-find-path-upstream

Comment: For automation of ArcGIS Desktop workflows I recommend exploring ArcPy.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.